# preg_match_all occurrences inside of a tag

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I've practiced plenty on http://regex101.com/ but have been unable for the life of me to preg match correctly.

I'm trying to fetch part of the onclick function from multiple tags, but it just makes a mess.

```
<a href="https://URL" onclick="return ajax({code:'page/97b7a6651b9f3f3H',form_id:'id456',top:0,update_id:'inner-container'});" class="get-button" target="_top"><span class="button"><span class="icon">&nbsp;</span>Attack</span></a>

<a href="https://URL" onclick="return ajax({code:'page/97b7a6651b96c6b7e398f',form_id:'id123',top:0,update_id:'inner-container'});" class="get-button" target="_top"><span class="button"><span class="icon">&nbsp;</span>Attack</span></a>
```

Its returning like this -> 3dc061fb74fe59orm_id:'bounty_attack_form_515998115'});" class="get-button" target="_top"> Attack

Where as I only want the 97b7a6651b9f3f3H and 97b7a6651b96c6b7e398f.

I've tried multiple ways and I know this php code is wrong but this what I have.
    preg_match_all("/ge/(.*)',f/", $server_output, $matches);
$remove = array("ge/","',f");

```
foreach ($matches[0] as $match) 
{ 
$match = str_replace($remove, "", $match);
    echo '[ ' . $match . ' ]<br>'; 
}
```

Comment: I've practiced plenty on http://regex101.com/ but have been unable for the life of me to preg match correctly.. Haven't practiced plenty! :-)

Comment: Seriously though, You don't need to use preg_match to find something, then replace it with str_replace. You could use preg_replace and apply the same regex rule. http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: I was only str_replacing because it was leaving extra code that I couldn't preg match correctly. I looked at the url you posted but if the variable isn't always the same then I cannot do that.

Comment: We can only answer solutions with the code you give us to fix...

Comment: I recommend NOT using regex to parse HTML, try a HTML parser like [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) or [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing there is a cleaner way to do this, but this works:

```
$string = "<a href=\"https://URL\" onclick=\"return ajax({code:'page/97b7a6651b9f3f3H',form_id:'id456',top:0,update_id:'inner-container'});\" class=\"get-button\" target=\"_top\"><span class=\"button\"><span class=\"icon\">&nbsp;</span>Attack</span></a>";

$string .= "<a href=\"https://URL\" onclick=\"return ajax({code:'page/97b7a6651b9f3f3H',form_id:'id456',top:0,update_id:'inner-container'});\" class=\"get-button\" target=\"_top\"><span class=\"button\"><span class=\"icon\">&nbsp;</span>Attack</span></a>";

preg_match_all("/code:\'page\/(.*?)\'/", $string, $matches);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    if (isset($match[1])) {
        $codes[] = $matches[1];
    } 
}

var_dump($codes);
```

See it in action:
http://ideone.com/YkIWig

If someone more regex smart than me wants to edit this, please do!

Comment: Can you add the above tags to your string for me to test. I'm certain this was the right approach but when I ran it I still had a few extra stuff trailing.

Comment: If you mean the full <a href etc etc string, then sure, it will still match against the whole string.

Comment: Multiple A tags. I was able to do it with just one, but when there are like 10 or more it isn't the same.

Comment: I understand now. Here you got, preg_match_all will find multiple occurances. I assumed you knew how to loop over multiple strings.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was looking for. I wasn't doing this
if (isset($match[1])) {
            $codes[] = $matches[1];
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all("/page\/\K\w*/", $string_to_search, $array);
print_r($array);
```

matches page/ exactly, \K removes the matched part, then it allows for any number of letters or digits until it hits a non-letter or digit, like the '

results go into an array and can be accessed as $array[0][x]

Comment: This is the closest yet. Thank you. I was hoping I wouldn't have to delete anything.

Comment: edited to add \K which will automatically remove the matched page/

Comment: \K makes it comeback empty.

Comment: works here: http://ideone.com/FwilCK

Seems \K is not supported below PHP v5.2.4.

Comment: That's nice. Now I'm going to update my php version.

Comment: Is it possible to join two different patterns this way?
page/97b7a6651b9f3f3H',form_id:'id456' to 97b7a6651b9f3f3H|id456